# How to Populate Combobox Based on User Input Using MVP?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, mvp

How To Populate a ComboBox Based on User Input Using C# and WinForms?

I have a combobox which I need to populate based on user input (2 different options), while also using the MVP pattern (Model View Presenter). This is in a C# WinForms project.

For example purposes, let's say I have 2 different categories: Fruits and Shoes. If the user chooses Fruits, then my combobox should populate with fruits, if my user chooses Shoes, then my combobox should populate with shoes.

My category data (Fruits and Shoes) are both stored in separate tables in my database.

Currently I have a Model, View, and Presenter for both categories, which works great, but seems very repetitive (especially when dealing with more than 2 categories). Is there an additional piece/design pattern I can implement to cut down on the repetitiveness?

I have provided some example code below, in the following order:
 1. Model, View, and Presenter for Fruits category
 2. Model, View, and Presenter for Shoes category
 3. WinForms Code Behind Page

```
////////FRUITS MVP////////

//Model
public class FruitsComboBoxModel
{
    public List<Fruits> Fruits { get; set; }
}

//View
public interface IFruitsComboBoxModel
{
    void ShowFruitsComboBox(FruitsComboBoxModel fruitsComboBoxModel);    
}

//Presenter
public class FruitsComboBoxPresenter
{
    IFruitsComboBoxView fruitsComboBoxView;

    public FruitsComboBoxPresenter(IFruitsComboBoxView view)
    {
        fruitsComboBoxView = view;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        var model = GetModel();
        fruitsComboBoxView.ShowFruitsComboBox(model);
    }

    private FruitsComboBoxModel GetModel()
    {
        var dbFruits = GetFruitsFromDataBase(); //fake call to DB for fruits
        var fruitsComboBoxModel = new FruitsComboBoxModel
        {
            Fruits = dbFruits;
        }
        return fruitsComboBoxModel;
    }
}

////////SHOES MVP////////

//Model
public class ShoesComboBoxModel
{
    public List<Shoes> Shoes { get; set; }
}

//View
public interface IShoesComboBoxModel
{
    void ShowShoesComboBox(ShoesComboBoxModel shoesComboBoxModel);
}

//Presenter
public class ShoesComboBoxPresenter
{
    IShoesComboBoxView shoesComboBoxView;

    public ShoesComboBoxPresenter(IShoesComboBoxView view)
    {
        shoesComboBoxView = view;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        var model = GetModel();
        shoesComboBoxView.ShowShoesComboBox(model);
    }

    private ShoesComboBoxModel GetModel()
    {
        var dbShoes = GetShoesFromDataBase(); //fake call to DB for shoes
        var shoesComboBoxModel = new ShoesComboBoxModel
        {
            Shoes = dbShoes;
        }
        return shoesComboBoxModel;
    }
}


////////Code Behind Page////////

public partial class ExampleForm : Form, IFruitsComboBoxView, IShoesComboBoxView
{
    public CategoryType categoryType { get; set; }
    FruitsComboBoxPresenter fruitsComboBoxPresenter;
    ShoesComboBoxPresenter shoesComboBoxPresenter;

    public ExampleForm(CategoryType type)
    {
        categoryType = type; //user category selection
    }

    private void ExampleForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (categoryType == CategoryType.Fruits)
        {
            fruitsComboBoxPresenter = new FruitsComboBoxPresenter(this);
            fruitsComboBoxPresenter.Init();
        }
        else if (categoryType == CategoryType.Shoes)
        {
            shoesComboBoxPresenter = new ShoesComboBoxPresenter(this);
            shoesComboBoxPresenter.Init();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid type detected");
        }
    }

    public void ShowFruitsComboBox(FruitsComboBoxModel fruitsComboBoxModel)
    {
        comboBox.DataSource = fruitsComboBoxModel.Fruits.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    }

    public void ShowShoesComboBox(ShoesComboBoxModel shoesComboBoxModel)
    {
        comboBox.DataSource = shoesComboBoxModel.Shoes.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```

I have debated using only one Model, View, and Presenter for the combobox and on my model having a fruits property (list) and having a shoes property (shoes). But this means I will have a lot of if/else logic inside my model, and have to pass down the user selection.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make use of some interfaces and abstract classes to reduce some of your duplicate code.

This will require some tweaking, but if you have some compile-able code I can take another look.

```
public interface IComboItem {
    string Name {get; set;}
    object Value {get; set;}
}
public class Fruit : IComboItem {
    //fruit stuff
}
public class Shoe : IComboItem {
    //shoe stuff
}

//View
public interface IComboBoxModel
{
    void ShowComboBox(List<IComboItem> comboItems);    
}

//Presenter
public abstract class ComboBoxPresenter {
    IComboBoxView comboBoxView;
    public ComboBoxPresenter(IComboBoxView view){
        comboBoxView = view;
    }
    public void Init(){
        var model = GetModel();
        comboBoxView.ShowComboBox(model);
    }
    //force implementors to get the model
    private abstract List<IComboItem> GetModel();
}
public class FruitsComboBoxPresenter : ComboBoxPresenter
{
    private override List<Fruit> GetModel()
    {
        return GetFruitsFromDataBase(); //fake call to DB for fruits
    }
}

public class ShoeComboBoxPresenter : ComboBoxPresenter
{
    private override List<Shoe> GetModel()
    {
        return GetShoesFromDataBase(); //fake call to DB for fruits
    }
}

////////Code Behind Page////////

public partial class ExampleForm : Form, IComboBoxView
{
    public CategoryType categoryType { get; set; }
    IComboBoxPresenter comboBoxPresenter;

    public ExampleForm(CategoryType type)
    {
        categoryType = type; //user category selection
    }

    private void ExampleForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (categoryType == CategoryType.Fruits)
        {
            comboBoxPresenter = new FruitsComboBoxPresenter(this);
        }
        else if (categoryType == CategoryType.Shoes)
        {
            comboBoxPresenter = new ShoesComboBoxPresenter(this);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid type detected");
        }
        comboBoxPresenter.Init();
    }

    public void ShowComboBox(List<IComboItem> comboItems)
    {
        comboBox.DataSource = comboItems.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest one view for one presenter. If you need use the multi-model write the code into presenter.

1. Create the Contract class then define the View and Presenter Interface

> ```
> public class ExampleFormContract
> {
>     public interface IView
>     {
>         // Display the item to the view
>         void DisplayComboBoxItems(IEnumerable<string> items);
>
>         // set the presneter 
>         IPresenter Presenter { set; }
>     }
>
>     public interface IPresenter
>     {
>         // init form load
>         void Init();
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Create ExampleFormPresenter and implement the ExampleFormContract.IPresenter

> ```
> public class ExampleFormPresenter : ExampleFormContract.IPresenter
> {
>     private ExampleFormContract.IView View { get; set; }
>
>     private CategoryType Type { get; set; }
>
>     public ExampleFormPresenter(ExampleFormContract.IView view, CategoryType type)
>     {
>         // set the view and use the Dependency Injection (IoC)
>         View = view;
>         View.Presenter = this;
>
>         Type = type;
>     }
>
>     public void Init()
>     {
>         // you can write your logic code to here.
>         if (Type == CategoryType.Fruits)
>         {
>             var dbFruits = GetFruitsFromDataBase(); //fake call to DB for fruits
>             var fruitsLists = dbFruits.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
>
>             // update the item to the view
>             View.DisplayComboBoxItems(fruitsLists);
>         }
>         else if (Type == CategoryType.Shoes)
>         {
>            var dbShoes = GetShoesFromDataBase(); //fake call to DB for shoes
>            var shoesLists = dbShoes.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
>
>            // update the item to the view
>            View.DisplayComboBoxItems(shoesLists);
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             throw new Exception("Invalid type detected");
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Modify the ExampleForm.cs implement ExampleFormContract.IView

> ```
> public partial class ExampleForm : Form, ExampleFormContract.IView
> {
>     // set the presenter
>     public ExampleFormContract.IPresenter Presenter { private get; set; }
>
>     public ExampleForm()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
>
>     private void ExampleForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         Presenter.Init();
>     }
>
>     public void DisplayComboBoxItems(IEnumerable<string> items)
>     {
>         // update the view
>         comboBox.DataSource = items;
>     }    
> }
> ```

4. Demo

> ```
> static void Main()
> {
>     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
>     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
>
>     // create the form
>     var form = new ExampleForm();
>
>     // use the IoC and Inject the CategoryType what you want
>     var presneter = new ExampleFormPresenter(form, CategoryType.Fruits);
>
>     Application.Run(form);
> }
> ```

This MVP architecture work fine for me into C# winform. I think it will help you.